# Node.js GC with unassigned function constructs

Tags: node.js, v8

I know it's generally considered best practice in javascript to always assign a `new` function to a variable, even if it's not used.  But in relation to garbage collection in node.js, is v8 able to GC functions that are not assigned to variables or does it make no difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as all references to a variable (anonymous or assigned) have been destroyed (in this case, by deallocation of the containing function) v8 should garbage collect it.